# flask-sqlalchemy - PostgreSQL - Define specific schema for table?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to define a specific schema for a 'model' using flask-sqlalchemy. When you create a table object in sqlalchemy itself it has a parameter to pass for schema name.

How do I do this in flask-sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

When you define your model class use:

```
__table_args__ = {"schema":"schema_name"}
```

maybe it will save someone else some hunting.

Comment: but is there any way to define schema in config file ?

Comment: Super helpful, and I believe this works b/c flask-sqlalchemy defers to sqlalchemy.orm under the hood. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_tables.html#explicit-schema-name-with-declarative-table

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it but I am also looking for a better way if possible -

```
db = flask.ext.sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy(app)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'your_default_schema_db_uri'

class Entity():
    __table_args__ = {
        'schema': 'schema_name'
    }
    # common columns below

class TableA(Entity, db.Model):
    # This belongs to Default schema, it doesn't need specify __bind_key__
    __table_args__ = {'schema' : Entity.__table_args__["schema"], 
                      'comment': 'TableA'}

class TableB(Entity, db.Model):
      # This belongs to other_schema
    __table_args__ = {'schema' : Entity.__table_args__["schema"], 
                      'comment': 'TableA'}
```

Answer (score -1):

For future references:

```
db = flask.ext.sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy(app)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'your_default_schema_db_uri'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {'other_schema': 'your_other_db_uri'}

class TableA(db.Model):
    # This belongs to Default schema, it doesn't need specify __bind_key__
    ...

class TableB(db.Model):
      # This belongs to other_schema
    __bind_key__ = 'other_schema'
    ...
```

Comment: With the wink and all, this answer is still wrong. You're mixing databases and schemas. Binds provides a way to handle connections to different databases more or less transparently. A database contains one or more schemas. Some RDBMS such as MySQL do consider them equivalent.