# How to target PostgreSQL schema in SQLAlchemy DB URI?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I understand that I can set `search_path` for the db role used to log in, but is there a way to specify the schema at the URI level or something to that effect? I may be mistaken due to my PostgreSQL experience being only with the [JDBC driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html).

My current URI fails:

```
postgresql://app_user:pw@localhost/dev_db?currentSchema=app
```

`psycopg2` is complaining about `currentSchema` being an invalid option

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) invalid dsn: invalid connection option "currentSchema"
 (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Comment: You have tagged flask-sqlalchemy. Do you have model creations as well?

Comment: There will be. I haven't written the models yet. I came across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873959/flask-sqlalchemy-postgresql-define-specific-schema-for-table) if we're talking about the schema option in models.

Comment: Exactly, I dont think Postgres still support schema param in connection uri. Workaround would be to connect to the db and change the search path as you mentioned

Comment: [Specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49930672/918959) this answer but alternatives are also discussed.